# Cannot import all user from openLDAP in Liferay 6.1

Tags: liferay

On my system, there are users about 20,000+ , but I can not finish to import users from openLDAP. The Users was imported until 10,335 and they just stop to import. It's seem they just stop at 10,000 without any log error.

(Before, I just could import user about 1,000, but I search another sites and someone suggest to use ldap.page.size , so I try to use ldap.page.size=30000 and they just stop import at 10,000)

```
My Server:
- liferay-portal-tomcat-6.1.2-ce-ga3 (bundle with tomcat)
- PostgresSQL9.3
- Open LDAP 2.4.23

My config:
ldap.import.method=user
ldap.page.size=30000
index.search.limit=50000
organizations.search.with.index=false
users.search.with.index=false
```

- I have restarted many times but no more any user import to Liferay.
  Help me please!!

Answer (score 0):

This is not affected from Liferay end and also page size is for number of records fetched in one go by LDAP,hence the above solutions do not work out well.I do not have openLDAP server installed currently but as per the given link [openLDAP specs](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/guide.html#Specifying%20size%20limits), these limits are specified from ldap end in order to maintain system performace.Try fiddling with **cachesize** and **idlcachesize** properties(both with default values of 10000),at openldap side,to fix this limitation.
Let me know your findings.